# UIViewRepresentable creating new instance on state change

Tags: swift, uikit, uiviewrepresentable, maplibre-gl

I'm new to Swift/UIKit and am trying to implement a MapLibreGL map that displays a list of markers. As the user changes search criteria, the list of markers changes, and I'm struggling to update the markers when this changes.

The challenge I'm facing is that when my state changes, the MapView UIViewRepresentable seems to be reinitialized, resulting in a new mapView object (MGLMapView).

On state change, updateUIView is called, but makeUIView and the coordiniator's init aren't called again (they're only called on first load).

When I then try to add/remove annotations to mapView, it's referencing the wrong mapView (the new one, that I don't believe is actually being displayed), and my view isn't updating.

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var mapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero) //this object is recreated when my state changes
    var symbols: Binding<[MapMarkerSymbol]>?
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: Context) {
        print("*****UPDATING******")
        //        This gets hit on state change
       
        //        let x = uiView.annotations;
        //        let y = mapView.annotations;
        // on intial load uiView and mapView reference the same object
        //on future state changes, they reference different objects
        
        context.coordinator.reload()
    }

     func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MGLMapView {
        print("****MAKING***")
        //      This only gets hit on first load
        let styleURL = getStyleURL()
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.logoView.isHidden = true
        mapView.styleURL = styleURL
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }
    func createMarkerSymbol(symbol: MapMarkerSymbol) {
        let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: symbol.lat, longitude: symbol.lng)
        annotation.title = symbol.title
        annotation.subtitle = ""
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, MGLMapViewDelegate {
        var control: MapView
        
        init(_ control: MapView) {
            self.control = control
        }
        func reload(){
            //this should remove the old annotations, and add a new set.
            //On state changes, the correct new set is being passed, but the mapView reference 
            //I get here is a new one, not the original one (that's being displayed), so it 
            //has no annotations to remove, and adding new ones to it doesn't impact the UI
           
            control.mapView.removeAnnotations(control.mapView.annotations ?? [])
            if let symbols = control.symbols{
                for symbol in symbols.wrappedValue {
                    control.createMarkerSymbol(symbol: symbol)
                }
            }
        }
        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
            
            print("*** DID FINISH LOADING *****")
            
            if !(control.symbols?.isEmpty ?? true) {
                control.zoomToBounds()
            }
            
        }
        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
            // Always allow callouts to popup when annotations are tapped.
            return true
        }
        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
            print("annotation tapped")
        }
        
    }
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> MapView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
```

I have tried with my "symbols" as a binding value and just a list, but it doesn't make a difference.

Here's a snipped of where this is being used:

```
    @StateObject private var viewModel = IOSFindBusinessesViewModel()
      var body: some View {
        @State var state = viewModel.state
       
            ZStack{
                if(state.isShowingMapLayout){
                    let businessPins = state.finalResultsToDisplay().map{business in
                        MapMarkerSymbol(lat: business.lat, lng: business.lng, title: business.name)
                    }
                        MapView(mapFiles: state.mapFiles, symbols: Binding(get: {
                            businessPins
                        }, set: { _ in
                            
                        }) )
                            
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    }
                
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the UIViewRepresentable being "partially recreated" - the mapView object is new, but the mapView that's being displayed (and the uiView provided in updateUIView) are the original views that were first created.

How can I maintain a reference to that original mapView so I can interact with it elsewhere?

Comment: Make your `MGLMapView` inside `makeUIView`. Then, in `updateUIView`, you get that `MGLMapView` passed in as the first parameter. Your coordinator can have a reference to the `MGLMapView` but _not_ the `MapView`

Comment: Thanks @jnpdx, but I couldn't follow how to implement this. Every example I can find (e.g. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-swiftui-demo/blob/master/MapboxSwiftUIDemo/MapView.swift) has the MGLMapView created on the UIViewRepresntable creation, and the coordinator has a reference to MapView. Moving  `var mapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero)` inside `makeUIView` means the rest of the code isn't able to use it (e.g. center and zoom in link provided, which were left out of original question for brevity). Can you provide a little code to get me started?

Comment: No, I can't really provide code because I'm not going to download the external library in order to make a concrete answer that I don't think runs the risk of being "wrong" somehow. What I _can_ tell you is that the code you linked to is _not good_. Heavy things like creating a view like that should _never_ be done in a property like that. You may want to watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC to see why. If you edit your question with your attempt, I'm happy to take a look, though

Comment: After a week playing with this, I'm still no further. Literally every single example I can find creates the view like this, including Amazon's docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/tutorial-maplibre-ios.html), and MapLibre's own docs. These examples have functions to center the map and set zoom levels, so they can be set externally, and these functions reference that MGLMapView property on the UIViewRepresentable. I'm really not sure where to go, I've tried dozens of things but nothing has got me any closer!

Comment: @CharlieWalker did you figure it out? gpt4 is now pretty good at ingesting docs on recent tools and asking for sample code with some prompt tweaking and retries